# Different transition-delay - animation finished vs not finished (css only)

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, delay

SOLUTION:
The solution I found is using two divs on top of each other(to make the function clearer I made one of the divs red), while it has to animate two divs for the effect, it should still be cleaner and faster than using javascript:

```css
 .outerDiv {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .hover1 {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            background: black;
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
            transition: width 1s
        }

        .hover2 {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            background: red;
            position: relative;
            top: -50px;
            transition: width 1s 1s
        }

        .outerDiv:hover .hover2 {
            width: 100%;
            transition: width 0s 0.9s;
        }

        .outerDiv:hover .hover1 {
            width: 100%;
            transition: width 1s;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="outerDiv">
        <div class="hover1"></div>
        <div class="hover2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by specifying different transition time for the normal state and hover state.

```
<style>
    #hoverDiv {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background: black;
        transition: width 5s; /*Specify required time. 
                               This affects how long it takes to transition 
                               back to the normal state*/


    }  


    #hoverDiv:hover {
       width: 100%;
       transition: width 2s; /*This affects how long it takes to transition 
                               into the hover state*/ 
 }
</style>
<div id="hoverDiv"></div>
```

Also, if you want to add a delay before width decreases back to normal, try

```
 #hoverDiv {
         height: 50px;
         width: 50px;
         background: black;
         transition: width 5s;
         transition-delay: 5s; /*Waits for 5 seconds and then decreases 
                               back to normal size in 5 seconds*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but that wasn't it. But I found the solution I was looking for.